# Total Answer Count

Tags: mysql, count

I am trying to get total answer count for the question. (Please refer attached image for table  structure)

Somehow I found this code which I believe similar to what I am looking for but not sure how to display total answers count (type = A in database)

```
SELECT * FROM ^posts a, ^posts q WHERE a.parentid=q.postid AND a.type="A" AND q.type="Q"
```

[image]

Comment: you mean select count(*) from table?

Comment: Are you trying to get a count of answers for each question?

Comment: @gtgaxiola
Yes total count of the answer for each question

Comment: @BrianHoover,
Yes total answer count for each question like question 1 has 5 answer, question 2 has 7 answer like that..

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM [table] WHERE type = 'A' GROUP BY parentid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select q.postid, count(a.postid) from posts q 
left outer join posts a on q.postid = a.parentid
where q.type = 'Q' 
group by q.postid
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want total number of answers (type = 'A'), Peter gave you the answer.

If you want to know the number of answers to a particular question,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts a, posts q 
WHERE a.parentid = q.postid 
AND a.type='A' AND q.type='Q' 
AND q.postid = <question_id_for_which_you_need_answer_count>
```

Answer (score 1):

Join back to the table to look at the answers.  LEFT JOIN in case there are no answers:

```
SELECT q.postid, count(a.*)
FROM posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts a ON p.postid = a.parentid
WHERE p.type = "Q"
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: What GROUP BY does? Actually I have never used GROUP BY so dont have much knowledge for that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table] WHERE type = 'A'
```

(Insert your table name for [table])

Comment: But this will count answer for all question not for each question

Comment: Yes, it is the total count of all answers.

Comment: I am looking for answer count for each question. like q1 has 3 answers, q2 has 7 answer and so on..